# Health is draining even after leaving the Soul Cairn

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dawnguard

I did something that a lot of players did, and tried to go back to the Soul Cairn after turning back into a human. But I saw that it was draining my health, so I went to Serana and turned back into a vampire.

After that, I went back to the Soul Cairn and after going through the portal, it was still draining my health. I decided to just go back, but even after that wherever I go it's still draining my health and I keep dying.

Is there any solution or command that could fix it? My last save was a lot of levels away.

Comment: Did you try to active god mode, leave the room and deactivate it?

Comment: I did but it didn't work. Even in god mode it's still draining my health.

Answer (score 2):

When you do the quest to enter the Soul Cairn, you have to 'soul trap' your soul so it doesn't take that damage if you side with the dawnguard. It is possible that when you turned into a human, you needed to do this in order to enter, and that turning  back into a vampire didn't change you back to being able to do it without doing the human side of the quest.